# Add variable text (sequential small letters) to query results

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I'm getting strings like the following at Col B on Page3 of this [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1B6rOWJYoDNaE6nuZjs1Six3fkxMph4fabam2R2NJwyI/edit#gid=1546830532):

> ) Reason1, Name: Bruno (2º OfSC, 3844923);
>  ) Reason1, Name:
> Wladimir (3º OfSC, 3693237);
>  ) Reason2, Name: Jorge (9º OfSC,
> 4715814);
>  ) Reason3, Name: Holden (1º OfSC, 4541195);
>  )
> Reason4, Name: John (5º OfSC, 4729589);
>  ) Reason5, Name: Antony
> (6º OfSC);
>  ) Reason5, Name: Edson (7º OfSC);

Is there a way to use `CHAR(ROW(97))` or `lower(regexreplace(address(1,row(A1)),"[^A-Z]",""))` into the formula `=IFERROR(  TEXTJOIN( CHAR(10); TRUE; TRANSPOSE(  QUERY(Page2!$A$3:$C; "select C where A <= date '" & TEXT( DATEVALUE(A4); "yyyy-mm-dd") & "' and (B >= date '" & TEXT( DATEVALUE(A4); "yyyy-mm-dd") & "' or B is null)"))))` to get the following result?

> a) Reason1, Name: Bruno (2º OfSC, 3844923);
>  b) Reason1, Name:
> Wladimir (3º OfSC, 3693237);
>  c) Reason2, Name: Jorge (9º OfSC,
> 4715814);
>  d) Reason3, Name: Holden (1º OfSC, 4541195);
>  e)
> Reason4, Name: John (5º OfSC, 4729589);
>  f) Reason5, Name: Antony
> (6º OfSC);
>  g) Reason5, Name: Edson (7º OfSC);

I have unsuccessful tried `=  TEXTJOIN( CHAR(10); TRUE; TRANSPOSE( ARRAYFORMULA  QUERY({CHAR(ROW(97)&Page2!$A$3:$C}; "select C where A <= date '" & TEXT( DATEVALUE(A4); "yyyy-mm-dd") & "' and (B >= date '" & TEXT( DATEVALUE(A4); "yyyy-mm-dd") & "' or B is null)")))` on Page3's Col C

Also, it would be great if the formula could be an array!

Comment: Would you be open to not using an array formula here? Or, alternatively, using an Apps Script [custom function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)?

Comment: Yes ! Also, I'm open to a drag down formula

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at your sample sheet there is a new tab called MK.Idea.

In it you will find this formula in cell I1:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(IFERROR(SPLIT(FLATTEN(Page1!E3:E70&", Name:"&Page1!C3:C70&" ("&Page1!D3:D70&IF(LEN(Page1!F3:F70);", "&Page1!F3:F70;)&")|"&Page1!A3:A70+SEQUENCE(1;L2;0)&"|"&TEXT(Page1!A3:A70+SEQUENCE(1;L2;0);"mmmyyyy")&"|"&(1*SUBSTITUTE(Page1!B3:B70;"undefined";TODAY())));"|";0;0));"select Col2,Col1 where Col2<=Col4 and Col3 = "&DATE(A1;A2;1)&" order by Col2 label Col2'Date',Col1'Reason'"))
```

Which does all of the work directly from the Page1 tab.  It does not use anything besides the original data. So Page2 and Page 3 are not necessary.

This formula supplies dynamic dates:

```
={"Date";SEQUENCE(DAY(EOMONTH(DATE(A1;A2;1);0));1;DATE(A1;A2;1))}
```

Then an "Filter" type formula built as an arrayformula gets the result.

```
={"Reasons";ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(A4:A34;SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(QUERY(QUERY({F:F&"|"\CHAR(10)&H:H&G:G};"select MAX(Col2) group by Col2 pivot Col1");;9^9));" "&CHAR(10);";"&CHAR(10)));"|;"&CHAR(10);0);2;0))}
```

[Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18BCO0LtQxY5JWUXVHN2DL4aD3l5Q_x_kSF_xWHbebHc/edit), a copy of the OP's sheet with my solution will live in perpetuity.